# Using Pivot to Calculate % data change in last two days

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that contains a set of data that is being collected on a daily basis (I use SQL Server 2016)

```
Date        A     B     C    D
2017/5/22   1.1   2.1  3.1   4.1
2017/5/21   1.0   2.0  3.0   4.0
2017/5/20   0.9   1.9  2.9   3.9
2017/5/19   1.0   2.0  3.0   4.0
2017/5/18   1.1   2.1  3.1   4.1
```

I'm trying to write a query that will show me the last two days and the % change, returning the results as follows:

```
Field  Today   Yesterday  Change(%)
A       1.1       1.0       10.0%
B       2.1       2.0        5.0%
C       3.1       3.0        3.3%
D       4.1       4.0        2.5%
```

Is there a quick way to do this (I'm assuming pivot is involved somewhere but I really can't work this query out)

Comment: is the number of fields limited?

Comment: Yes. In the real world example I have 14 fields

Comment: And you want the `max(date)` as your base and calculate `today` and `yesterday` based on that?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd get the result by first using a windowing function, like `row_number` to get the top 2 dates, then unpivot your columns of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` into rows. Once you've done that, you can pivot those results to get the final desired product.

Breaking this down, I'd start by using `row_number`:

```
select [Date], A, B, C, D,
  rn = row_number() over(order by [Date] desc) 
from #yourtable
```

This creates a unique row id for each row in your table, you can order this by date to generate the dates in the order you'd like.  Next up, you'll unpivot your `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` columns into rows:

```
select 
  Field,
  value, 
  Dt = case when rn = 1 then 'Today' else 'Yesterday' end
from
(
  select [Date], A, B, C, D,
    rn = row_number() over(order by [Date] desc) 
  from #yourtable
) x
cross apply
(
  values
  ('A', A),
  ('B', B),
  ('C', C),
  ('D', D)  -- include additional columns here if you have more
) c (Field, value)
where rn <= 2 -- return top 2 dates
```

In this you'll convert your columns into rows and then only return those with the top 2 dates you want - today and yesterday. Finally, you'll pivot those `Today` and `Yesterday` values into columns and calculate your percent change. So putting it all together:

```
select 
  Field,
  Today, 
  Yesterday,
  ChangePercent = round((Today-Yesterday)/ Yesterday *100.0, 2)
from
(
  select 
    Field,
    value, 
    Dt = case when rn = 1 then 'Today' else 'Yesterday' end
  from
  (
    select [Date], A, B, C, D,
      rn = row_number() over(order by [Date] desc) 
    from #yourtable
  ) x
  cross apply
  (
    values
    ('A', A),
    ('B', B),
    ('C', C),
    ('D', D)
  ) c (Field, value)
  where rn <= 2 -- return top 2 dates
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for dt in (Today, Yesterday)
) piv
```

Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/675389). This gives you the results:

```
Field Today Yesterday ChangePercent 
----- ----- --------- ------------- 
A     1.1   1         10            
B     2.1   2         5             
C     3.1   3         3.33          
D     4.1   4         2.5
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked a treat and you explained what was going on very well.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need:

```
select
    FieldValue                          as  [Field]
    , case FieldValue 
        when 'A'
            then ta
        when 'B'
            then tb
        when 'C'
            then tc
        when 'D'
            then td
        end                             as  [Today]
    , case FieldValue 
        when 'A'
            then ya
        when 'B'
            then yb
        when 'C'
            then yc
        when 'D'
            then yd
        end                             as  [Yesterday]
    , Change                            as  [Change(%)]
    from
    (select
        t1.a                            as  [ta]    -- today's A value
        , t1.b                          as  [tb]    -- today's B value
        , t1.c                          as  [tc]    -- today's C value
        , t1.d                          as  [td]    -- today's D value
        --, t1.e                        as  [te]    -- today's E value
        -- make sure to include the t1.e, t1.f etc. for other Fields too

        , y.a                           as  [ya]    -- yesterday's A value
        , y.b                           as  [yb]    -- yesterday's B value
        , y.c                           as  [yc]    -- yesterday's C value
        , y.d                           as  [yd]    -- yesterday's D value
        --, y.e                         as  [ye]    -- yesterday's E value
        -- make sure to include the y.e, y.f etc. for other Fields too

        , 100 / (y.a / (t1.a - y.a))    as  [A]     -- A's change since yesterday
        , 100 / (y.b / (t1.b - y.b))    as  [B]     -- B's change since yesterday
        , 100 / (y.c / (t1.c - y.c))    as  [C]     -- C's change since yesterday
        , 100 / (y.d / (t1.d - y.d))    as  [D]     -- D's change since yesterday
        --, 100 / (y.e / t1.e - y.e))   as  [E]     -- E's change since yesterday (INCLUDE this "E" alias in the list of columns from UNPIVOT)
        -- make sure to add calculations for your other fields here too

    from baseTable t1
        cross apply (select top 1 * 
                     from baseTable t2 
                     where t2.date < t1.date) y
    where t1.date = (select max(date) from baseTable)
    ) result
unpivot (
    Change for FieldValue in (a, b, c, d) --, e, f etc.) -- enumerate all column ALIASES used in the sub-select, where the CHANGE is calculated
    ) as unpvt
```

Just make sure to extend the `CASE` statements and `UNPIVOT` columns with all your values as well as the `100 / (x.a / (t1.a - x.a))` with all of your other fields.

**Script I used to generate sample data:** *(ideally you should have provided this)*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[baseTable](
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [a] [numeric](18, 1) NULL,
    [b] [numeric](18, 1) NULL,
    [c] [numeric](18, 1) NULL,
    [d] [numeric](18, 1) NULL
)

GO
INSERT [dbo].[baseTable] ([date], [a], [b], [c], [d]) VALUES (CAST(N'2017-05-22' AS Date), CAST(1.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(2.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(3.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(4.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[baseTable] ([date], [a], [b], [c], [d]) VALUES (CAST(N'2017-05-21' AS Date), CAST(1.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(2.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(3.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(4.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[baseTable] ([date], [a], [b], [c], [d]) VALUES (CAST(N'2017-05-20' AS Date), CAST(0.9 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(1.9 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(2.9 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(3.9 AS Numeric(18, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[baseTable] ([date], [a], [b], [c], [d]) VALUES (CAST(N'2017-05-19' AS Date), CAST(1.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(2.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(3.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(4.0 AS Numeric(18, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[baseTable] ([date], [a], [b], [c], [d]) VALUES (CAST(N'2017-05-18' AS Date), CAST(1.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(2.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(3.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)), CAST(4.1 AS Numeric(18, 1)))
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I went for one of the more compact queries below but I appreciate the effort you put in.